# Alert message with textarea content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to alert whatever text is in a textarea (id="status_update") when the user hits enter:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('textarea').keypress(function(e) {

                    if(e.which == 13) {
                        var entry = $('#status_update').val;    
                        alert(entry);
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Alert bubble pops up when the user hits enter but the text says 'undefined'. I think there is some issue with the way I am trying to define the var entry but Im not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('#status_update').val()`

Answer (score 1):

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a function:

```
var entry = $('#status_update').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work better:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    var entry = $(this).val();    
    alert(entry);
  }
});
```

You should consider using console.log($("#status_update")) instead of alert for your testing, use it with firebug console in firefox, it's a developers best friend.

Comment: `console.log` is not availble in all browsers. `this.value` is much more efficient than `$(this).val()`.

Comment: True, but when developing I can't live without firebug, once I'm done I start testing other browsers. I believe Chrome also has it's own web developer bar, but any web developer that uses explorer when coding is a n00b lol

Answer (score 1):

And this should be even better:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    e.which == 13 ? alert($(this).val()) : "";
});
```